# case missing gke-spot label is it spot=false?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, k8s-serviceaccount

I need to know id node is spot or not. I found I can collect this data from node labels but case inside node details there is no GKE key label:

```
cloud.google.com/gke-spot: "true" / "false".
```

whats its mean? its mean default is not spot? I cant find any support documentation related this.
for example on EKS of AWS mentioned: "By default, if you don't specify a Capacity Type, the managed node group is provisioned with On-Demand Instances."

Comment: Can you please re-write your question. it's not very clear what the ask is

What do you mean by " case inside node details there is no GKE key label" ?

Comment: There is an other label you can use cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning. It has two values standard and spot. maybe this is what you need ?

Comment: yes you right. there is also cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning label. I don't understand why there is 2 labels for the same issue spot or not?

Answer (score 2):

GKE **does not use Spot** by default.  If the `cloud.google.com/gke-spot` label does not exist on the node, it is not spot.

If you are running **GKE 1.25.5-gke.2500 or later**, checking `cloud.google.com/gke-provisioning=spot` would be the preferred approach as well.